# Apache not sending POST data to PHP?

Tags: apache-2.2, php, http

I have written a simple command line program that opens a browser and posts data to a given url. For some reason once the request gets to my apache server, apache see's the post data, but fails to send it to PHP. When attempting to

> echo var_dump($_POST, true)

I see an empty array. I have setup mod_dumpio and can see the request coming in and the POST data is definitely there (I double spaced the line that shows apache receiving the post data so it's easier to locate below):

```
[Thu Jul 07 08:24:48 2016] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Debian) PHP/5.4.36-0+deb7u3 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Jul 07 08:25:22 2016] [debug] mod_dumpio.c(113): mod_dumpio: dumpio_in [getline-blocking] 0 readbytes
[Thu Jul 07 08:25:22 2016] [debug] mod_dumpio.c(55): mod_dumpio:  dumpio_in (data-HEAP): 17 bytes
[Thu Jul 07 08:25:22 2016] [debug] mod_dumpio.c(74): mod_dumpio:  dumpio_in (data-HEAP): POST / HTTP/1.1\r\n
[Thu Jul 07 08:25:22 2016] [debug] mod_dumpio.c(113): mod_dumpio: dumpio_in [getline-blocking] 0 readbytes
[Thu Jul 07 08:25:22 2016] [debug] mod_dumpio.c(55): mod_dumpio:  dumpio_in (data-HEAP): 47 bytes
[Thu Jul 07 08:25:22 2016] [debug] mod_dumpio.c(74): mod_dumpio:  dumpio_in (data-HEAP): Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*\r\n
[Thu Jul 07 08:25:22 2016] [debug] mod_dumpio.c(113): mod_dumpio: dumpio_in [getline-blocking] 0 readbytes
[Thu Jul 07 08:25:22 2016] [debug] mod_dumpio.c(55): mod_dumpio:  dumpio_in (data-HEAP): 49 bytes
[Thu Jul 07 08:25:22 2016] [debug] mod_dumpio.c(74): mod_dumpio:  dumpio_in (data-HEAP): Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n
[Thu Jul 07 08:25:22 2016] [debug] mod_dumpio.c(113): mod_dumpio: dumpio_in [getline-blocking] 0 readbytes
[Thu Jul 07 08:25:22 2016] [debug] mod_dumpio.c(55): mod_dumpio:  dumpio_in (data-HEAP): 24 bytes
[Thu Jul 07 08:25:22 2016] [debug] mod_dumpio.c(74): mod_dumpio:  dumpio_in (data-HEAP): Accept-Language: en-US\r\n
[Thu Jul 07 08:25:22 2016] [debug] mod_dumpio.c(113): mod_dumpio: dumpio_in [getline-blocking] 0 readbytes
[Thu Jul 07 08:25:22 2016] [debug] mod_dumpio.c(55): mod_dumpio:  dumpio_in (data-HEAP): 82 bytes
[Thu Jul 07 08:25:22 2016] [debug] mod_dumpio.c(74): mod_dumpio:  dumpio_in (data-HEAP): User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko\r\n
[Thu Jul 07 08:25:22 2016] [debug] mod_dumpio.c(113): mod_dumpio: dumpio_in [getline-blocking] 0 readbytes
[Thu Jul 07 08:25:22 2016] [debug] mod_dumpio.c(55): mod_dumpio:  dumpio_in (data-HEAP): 32 bytes
[Thu Jul 07 08:25:22 2016] [debug] mod_dumpio.c(74): mod_dumpio:  dumpio_in (data-HEAP): Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\n
[Thu Jul 07 08:25:22 2016] [debug] mod_dumpio.c(113): mod_dumpio: dumpio_in [getline-blocking] 0 readbytes
[Thu Jul 07 08:25:22 2016] [debug] mod_dumpio.c(55): mod_dumpio:  dumpio_in (data-HEAP): 19 bytes
[Thu Jul 07 08:25:22 2016] [debug] mod_dumpio.c(74): mod_dumpio:  dumpio_in (data-HEAP): Host: local.kiosk\r\n
[Thu Jul 07 08:25:22 2016] [debug] mod_dumpio.c(113): mod_dumpio: dumpio_in [getline-blocking] 0 readbytes
[Thu Jul 07 08:25:22 2016] [debug] mod_dumpio.c(55): mod_dumpio:  dumpio_in (data-HEAP): 20 bytes
[Thu Jul 07 08:25:22 2016] [debug] mod_dumpio.c(74): mod_dumpio:  dumpio_in (data-HEAP): Content-Length: 34\r\n
[Thu Jul 07 08:25:22 2016] [debug] mod_dumpio.c(113): mod_dumpio: dumpio_in [getline-blocking] 0 readbytes
[Thu Jul 07 08:25:22 2016] [debug] mod_dumpio.c(55): mod_dumpio:  dumpio_in (data-HEAP): 24 bytes
[Thu Jul 07 08:25:22 2016] [debug] mod_dumpio.c(74): mod_dumpio:  dumpio_in (data-HEAP): Connection: Keep-Alive\r\n
[Thu Jul 07 08:25:22 2016] [debug] mod_dumpio.c(113): mod_dumpio: dumpio_in [getline-blocking] 0 readbytes
[Thu Jul 07 08:25:22 2016] [debug] mod_dumpio.c(55): mod_dumpio:  dumpio_in (data-HEAP): 25 bytes
[Thu Jul 07 08:25:22 2016] [debug] mod_dumpio.c(74): mod_dumpio:  dumpio_in (data-HEAP): Cache-Control: no-cache\r\n
[Thu Jul 07 08:25:22 2016] [debug] mod_dumpio.c(113): mod_dumpio: dumpio_in [getline-blocking] 0 readbytes
[Thu Jul 07 08:25:22 2016] [debug] mod_dumpio.c(55): mod_dumpio:  dumpio_in (data-HEAP): 2 bytes
[Thu Jul 07 08:25:22 2016] [debug] mod_dumpio.c(74): mod_dumpio:  dumpio_in (data-HEAP): \r\n
[Thu Jul 07 08:25:22 2016] [debug] mod_dumpio.c(113): mod_dumpio: dumpio_in [readbytes-blocking] 34 readbytes
[Thu Jul 07 08:25:22 2016] [debug] mod_dumpio.c(55): mod_dumpio:  dumpio_in (data-HEAP): 34 bytes

[Thu Jul 07 08:25:22 2016] [debug] mod_dumpio.c(74): mod_dumpio:  dumpio_in (data-HEAP): mm=7H235727A768&mn=JKIUYRHT0081563

[Thu Jul 07 08:25:22 2016] [debug] mod_dumpio.c(143): mod_dumpio: dumpio_out
[Thu Jul 07 08:25:22 2016] [debug] mod_dumpio.c(55): mod_dumpio:  dumpio_out (data-HEAP): 271 bytes
[Thu Jul 07 08:25:22 2016] [debug] mod_dumpio.c(74): mod_dumpio:  dumpio_out (data-HEAP): HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nDate: Thu, 07 Jul 2016 13:25:22 GMT\r\nServer: Apache/2.2.22 (Debian)\r\nX-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.36-0+deb7u3\r\nVary: Accept-Encoding\r\nContent-Encoding: gzip\r\nContent-Length: 91\r\nKeep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100\r\nConnection: Keep-Alive\r\nContent-Type: text/html\r\n\r\n
[Thu Jul 07 08:25:22 2016] [debug] mod_dumpio.c(143): mod_dumpio: dumpio_out
[Thu Jul 07 08:25:22 2016] [debug] mod_dumpio.c(55): mod_dumpio:  dumpio_out (data-IMMORTAL): 10 bytes
[Thu Jul 07 08:25:22 2016] [debug] mod_dumpio.c(74): mod_dumpio:  dumpio_out (data-IMMORTAL): \x1f\x8b\b
[Thu Jul 07 08:25:22 2016] [debug] mod_dumpio.c(55): mod_dumpio:  dumpio_out (data-HEAP): 73 bytes
[Thu Jul 07 08:25:22 2016] [debug] mod_dumpio.c(74): mod_dumpio:  dumpio_out (data-HEAP): \xcb\xc9ON\xcc\xb1I*\xd2\xb7\x83\x10\x05E\xa9v\x89EE\x89\x95\n\x1a\\\n\n\xea\xb9\xb9\xea\n\xb6v\n\xeaF\xceF\xe6.\xe6F\xe6\x8e\xc6ff\xea:`\x99<\x88\x8c\xbf\xa3\xa7\x97s\x88K\xa8\x81\x81\x85\xa1\x89\xa9)PR\x13
[Thu Jul 07 08:25:22 2016] [debug] mod_dumpio.c(55): mod_dumpio:  dumpio_out (data-POOL): 8 bytes
[Thu Jul 07 08:25:22 2016] [debug] mod_dumpio.c(74): mod_dumpio:  dumpio_out (data-POOL): \x89\x02;[T
[Thu Jul 07 08:25:22 2016] [debug] mod_dumpio.c(55): mod_dumpio:  dumpio_out (metadata-EOS): 0 bytes
[Thu Jul 07 08:25:22 2016] [debug] mod_dumpio.c(113): mod_dumpio: dumpio_in [eatcrlf-nonblocking] 0 readbytes
[Thu Jul 07 08:25:22 2016] [debug] mod_dumpio.c(127): mod_dumpio: dumpio_in - 11
[Thu Jul 07 08:25:22 2016] [debug] mod_dumpio.c(143): mod_dumpio: dumpio_out
[Thu Jul 07 08:25:22 2016] [debug] mod_dumpio.c(55): mod_dumpio:  dumpio_out (metadata-FLUSH): 0 bytes
[Thu Jul 07 08:25:22 2016] [debug] mod_dumpio.c(113): mod_dumpio: dumpio_in [getline-blocking] 0 readbytes
[Thu Jul 07 08:25:22 2016] [debug] mod_dumpio.c(55): mod_dumpio:  dumpio_in (data-HEAP): 16 bytes
[Thu Jul 07 08:25:22 2016] [debug] mod_dumpio.c(74): mod_dumpio:  dumpio_in (data-HEAP): GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n
[Thu Jul 07 08:25:22 2016] [debug] mod_dumpio.c(113): mod_dumpio: dumpio_in [getline-blocking] 0 readbytes
[Thu Jul 07 08:25:22 2016] [debug] mod_dumpio.c(55): mod_dumpio:  dumpio_in (data-HEAP): 47 bytes
[Thu Jul 07 08:25:22 2016] [debug] mod_dumpio.c(74): mod_dumpio:  dumpio_in (data-HEAP): Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*\r\n
[Thu Jul 07 08:25:22 2016] [debug] mod_dumpio.c(113): mod_dumpio: dumpio_in [getline-blocking] 0 readbytes
[Thu Jul 07 08:25:22 2016] [debug] mod_dumpio.c(55): mod_dumpio:  dumpio_in (data-HEAP): 24 bytes
[Thu Jul 07 08:25:22 2016] [debug] mod_dumpio.c(74): mod_dumpio:  dumpio_in (data-HEAP): Accept-Language: en-US\r\n
[Thu Jul 07 08:25:22 2016] [debug] mod_dumpio.c(113): mod_dumpio: dumpio_in [getline-blocking] 0 readbytes
[Thu Jul 07 08:25:22 2016] [debug] mod_dumpio.c(55): mod_dumpio:  dumpio_in (data-HEAP): 82 bytes
[Thu Jul 07 08:25:22 2016] [debug] mod_dumpio.c(74): mod_dumpio:  dumpio_in (data-HEAP): User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko\r\n
[Thu Jul 07 08:25:22 2016] [debug] mod_dumpio.c(113): mod_dumpio: dumpio_in [getline-blocking] 0 readbytes
[Thu Jul 07 08:25:22 2016] [debug] mod_dumpio.c(55): mod_dumpio:  dumpio_in (data-HEAP): 32 bytes
[Thu Jul 07 08:25:22 2016] [debug] mod_dumpio.c(74): mod_dumpio:  dumpio_in (data-HEAP): Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\n
[Thu Jul 07 08:25:22 2016] [debug] mod_dumpio.c(113): mod_dumpio: dumpio_in [getline-blocking] 0 readbytes
[Thu Jul 07 08:25:22 2016] [debug] mod_dumpio.c(55): mod_dumpio:  dumpio_in (data-HEAP): 19 bytes
[Thu Jul 07 08:25:22 2016] [debug] mod_dumpio.c(74): mod_dumpio:  dumpio_in (data-HEAP): Host: local.kiosk\r\n
[Thu Jul 07 08:25:22 2016] [debug] mod_dumpio.c(113): mod_dumpio: dumpio_in [getline-blocking] 0 readbytes
[Thu Jul 07 08:25:22 2016] [debug] mod_dumpio.c(55): mod_dumpio:  dumpio_in (data-HEAP): 24 bytes
[Thu Jul 07 08:25:22 2016] [debug] mod_dumpio.c(74): mod_dumpio:  dumpio_in (data-HEAP): Connection: Keep-Alive\r\n
[Thu Jul 07 08:25:22 2016] [debug] mod_dumpio.c(113): mod_dumpio: dumpio_in [getline-blocking] 0 readbytes
[Thu Jul 07 08:25:22 2016] [debug] mod_dumpio.c(55): mod_dumpio:  dumpio_in (data-HEAP): 2 bytes
[Thu Jul 07 08:25:22 2016] [debug] mod_dumpio.c(74): mod_dumpio:  dumpio_in (data-HEAP): \r\n
[Thu Jul 07 08:25:22 2016] [debug] mod_dumpio.c(143): mod_dumpio: dumpio_out
[Thu Jul 07 08:25:22 2016] [debug] mod_dumpio.c(55): mod_dumpio:  dumpio_out (data-HEAP): 270 bytes
[Thu Jul 07 08:25:22 2016] [debug] mod_dumpio.c(74): mod_dumpio:  dumpio_out (data-HEAP): HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nDate: Thu, 07 Jul 2016 13:25:22 GMT\r\nServer: Apache/2.2.22 (Debian)\r\nX-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.36-0+deb7u3\r\nVary: Accept-Encoding\r\nContent-Encoding: gzip\r\nContent-Length: 44\r\nKeep-Alive: timeout=5, max=99\r\nConnection: Keep-Alive\r\nContent-Type: text/html\r\n\r\n
[Thu Jul 07 08:25:22 2016] [debug] mod_dumpio.c(143): mod_dumpio: dumpio_out
[Thu Jul 07 08:25:22 2016] [debug] mod_dumpio.c(55): mod_dumpio:  dumpio_out (data-IMMORTAL): 10 bytes
[Thu Jul 07 08:25:22 2016] [debug] mod_dumpio.c(74): mod_dumpio:  dumpio_out (data-IMMORTAL): \x1f\x8b\b
[Thu Jul 07 08:25:22 2016] [debug] mod_dumpio.c(55): mod_dumpio:  dumpio_out (data-HEAP): 26 bytes
[Thu Jul 07 08:25:22 2016] [debug] mod_dumpio.c(74): mod_dumpio:  dumpio_out (data-HEAP): \xcb\xc9ON\xcc\xb1I*\xd2\xb7\x83\x10\x05E\xa9v\x89EE\x89\x95\n\x1a\\\x9a
[Thu Jul 07 08:25:22 2016] [debug] mod_dumpio.c(55): mod_dumpio:  dumpio_out (data-POOL): 8 bytes
[Thu Jul 07 08:25:22 2016] [debug] mod_dumpio.c(74): mod_dumpio:  dumpio_out (data-POOL): \xac\xb0\x89\xac\x1d
[Thu Jul 07 08:25:22 2016] [debug] mod_dumpio.c(55): mod_dumpio:  dumpio_out (metadata-EOS): 0 bytes
[Thu Jul 07 08:25:22 2016] [debug] mod_dumpio.c(113): mod_dumpio: dumpio_in [eatcrlf-nonblocking] 0 readbytes
[Thu Jul 07 08:25:22 2016] [debug] mod_dumpio.c(127): mod_dumpio: dumpio_in - 11
[Thu Jul 07 08:25:22 2016] [debug] mod_dumpio.c(143): mod_dumpio: dumpio_out
[Thu Jul 07 08:25:22 2016] [debug] mod_dumpio.c(55): mod_dumpio:  dumpio_out (metadata-FLUSH): 0 bytes
[Thu Jul 07 08:25:22 2016] [debug] mod_dumpio.c(113): mod_dumpio: dumpio_in [getline-blocking] 0 readbytes
[Thu Jul 07 08:25:27 2016] [debug] mod_dumpio.c(127): mod_dumpio: dumpio_in - 70007
[Thu Jul 07 08:25:27 2016] [debug] mod_dumpio.c(143): mod_dumpio: dumpio_out
[Thu Jul 07 08:25:27 2016] [debug] mod_dumpio.c(55): mod_dumpio:  dumpio_out (metadata-FLUSH): 0 bytes
[Thu Jul 07 08:25:27 2016] [debug] mod_dumpio.c(55): mod_dumpio:  dumpio_out (metadata-EOC): 0 bytes
```

Any thoughts as to why PHP is not recognizing the post data?

Comment: What is your PHP configuration in Apache?

Comment: Is there any specific attribute you're looking for? Every other php application on the server works fine.